# In Swift, how do I generate a new struct each time the NavigationLink is clicked on

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to make a small sudoku game. I have 3 views, a WelcomeView, a GameView, and a CellView. I also have a Board.swift file.

The logic behind the game is that Board generates an [[Int]] and the GameView generates a cell for the 81 sudoku board cells. This is how the Board generates a new board:

```
import Foundation

class SudokuGenerator {
    func generateBoard() -> [[Int]] {
        var board = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: 9), count: 9)
        var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        numbers.shuffle()
        var count = 0
        for i in 0...2 {
            for j in 0...2 {
                board[i][j] = numbers[count]
                count += 1
            }
        }
        if (backtrack(board: &board, row: 0, col: 3)) {
            return board
        } else {
            return [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: 9), count: 9)
        }
    }
    private func backtrack(board: inout [[Int]], row: Int, col: Int) -> Bool {
        // check if we have reached 8th column
        var row = row
        var col = col
        if (col == 9) {
            col = 0
            row += 1
        }
        // check if we have reached 8th row
        if (row == 9) {
            return true
        }
        if (board[row][col] != 0) {
            return backtrack(board: &board, row: row, col: col + 1)
        }
        for num in 1...9 {
            if (isSafe(board: board, row: row, col: col, num: num)) {
                board[row][col] = num
                if (backtrack(board: &board, row: row, col: col + 1)) {
                    return true
                }
                board[row][col] = 0
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    private func isSafe(board: [[Int]], row: Int, col: Int, num: Int) -> Bool {
        // check in row
        for x in 0...8 {
            if board[row][x] == num {
                return false
            }
        }
        // check in column
        for x in 0...8 {
            if board[x][col] == num {
                return false
            }
        }
        // check in 3x3 sub-grid
        let startRow = (row / 3) * 3
        let startCol = (col / 3) * 3
        for i in startRow..<startRow + 3 {
            for j in startCol..<startCol + 3 {
                if board[i][j] == num {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}


struct Board: Equatable {
    enum Difficulty: Int, CaseIterable {
#if DEBUG
        case testing = 2
#endif
        case trivial = 10
        case easy = 20
        case medium = 24
        case hard = 27
        case extreme = 29
    }
    
    let size = 9
    let difficulty: Difficulty
    var fullBoard = [[Int]]()
    var playerBoard = [[Int]]()
    
    init(difficulty: Difficulty = .easy) {
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        create()
        prepareForPlay()
    }
    
    private mutating func create() {
        let generator = SudokuGenerator()
        fullBoard = generator.generateBoard()
        playerBoard = fullBoard
    }
    private mutating func prepareForPlay() {
        let empties = difficulty.rawValue
        let allCells = 0..<size * size / 2
        
        for cell in allCells.shuffled().prefix(upTo: empties) {
            let row = cell / size
            let column = cell % size
            playerBoard[row][column] = 0
            playerBoard[8 - row][8 - column] = 0
        }
    }
}
```

When a player clicks on a difficulty, it generates a board based on the difficulty:

```
import SwiftUI

struct WelcomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("SudokuHero")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Válassz nehézséget!")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        Text("Vigyázz, fokozattól függően változik a segítségek száma!")
                            .font(.callout)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        ForEach(Board.Difficulty.allCases, id: \.self) { difficulty in
                            NavigationLink(destination: GameView(difficulty: difficulty), label: {
                                Text("\(String(describing: difficulty).capitalized) fokozat")
                                    .font(.title).bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            })
                            .padding(.top, 1)
                            .padding(.trailing)
                            .background(Color.squareStandard)
                            .fixedSize()
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}

struct WelcomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WelcomeView()
    }
}
```

The game is working, it generates a board:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GameView: View {
    init(difficulty: Board.Difficulty) {
        board = Board(difficulty: difficulty)
        switch difficulty {
        case .testing, .easy, .trivial:
            availableHints = 10
        case .medium:
            availableHints = 5
        case .hard:
            availableHints = 3
        case .extreme:
            availableHints = 0
        }
    }
    
    @State private var board: Board
    @State private var availableHints: Int
    
    private let spacing = 1.0
    
    @State private var selectedRow = -1
    @State private var selectedCol = -1
    @State private var selectedNum = 0
    
    @State private var solved = false
    @State private var showingNewGame = false
    
    @State private var counts = [Int: Int]()
    
    @State private var showAllWrongCells = false
    @State private var hintCount = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Kérj segítséget a HELP gomb megnyomásával!")
                Text(getHintAvailable())
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Grid(horizontalSpacing: 1, verticalSpacing: 1) {
                    ForEach(0..<9) { row in
                        GridRow {
                            ForEach(0..<9) { col in
                                CellView(number: board.playerBoard[row][col], selectedNumber: selectedNum, highlightState: highlightState(for: row, col: col), isCorrect: board.playerBoard[row][col] == board.fullBoard[row][col], isAllowedToShowCorrect: showAllWrongCells) {
                                    selectedRow = row
                                    selectedCol = col
                                    selectedNum = board.playerBoard[row][col]
                                }
                                
                                if col == 2 || col == 5 {
                                    Spacer()
                                        .frame(width: spacing, height: 1)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, row == 2 || row == 5 ? spacing : 0)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 5.0)
                
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("""
H
E
L
P
""") {
                        if hintCount < availableHints {
                            showAllWrongCells = true
                            Task {
                                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
                                showAllWrongCells = false
                            }
                            hintCount += 1
                        }
                    }
.frame(width: 60)
.font(.title)
.disabled(board.difficulty != .extreme ? hintCount >= availableHints : true)
                    Grid {
                        ForEach (0..<3) { row in
                            GridRow {
                                ForEach(0..<3) { column in
                                    Button("\((row * 3) + column + 1)") {
                                        enter((row * 3) + column + 1)
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .background(Color.gray)
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .opacity(counts[((row * 3) + column + 1), default: 1] == 9 ? 0.5 : 1)
                                    .disabled(counts[((row * 3) + column + 1), default: 1] == 9)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 20.0)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("SudokuHero")
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    showingNewGame = true
                } label: {
                    Label("Új játék", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        .dynamicTypeSize(...DynamicTypeSize.xxxLarge)
        .alert("Új játék?", isPresented: $showingNewGame) {
            ForEach(Board.Difficulty.allCases, id: \.self) { difficulty in
                Button("\(String(describing: difficulty).capitalized) fokozat") {
                    newGame(difficulty: difficulty)
                    hintCount = 0
                }
            }
            
            Button("Mégse", role: .cancel) { }
        } message: {
            if solved {
                Text("Gratulálok, sikerült rájönnöd a megoldásra!")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: updateCounts)
        .onChange(of: board) { _ in
            updateCounts()
        }
    }
    
    func highlightState (for row: Int, col: Int) -> CellView.HighlightState {
        if row == selectedRow {
            if col == selectedCol {
                return .selected
            } else {
                return .highlighted
            }
        } else if col == selectedCol {
            return .highlighted
        } else {
            return .standard
        }
    }
    
    func enter(_ number: Int) {
        if selectedCol < 0 || selectedRow < 0 {
            return
        }
        if board.playerBoard[selectedRow][selectedCol] == number {
            board.playerBoard[selectedRow][selectedCol] = 0
            selectedNum = 0
        } else {
            board.playerBoard[selectedRow][selectedCol] = number
            selectedNum = number
        }
    }
    
    func newGame(difficulty: Board.Difficulty) {
        board = Board(difficulty: difficulty)
        selectedRow = -1
        selectedCol = -1
        selectedNum = 0
        
        switch difficulty {
        case .testing, .easy, .trivial:
            availableHints = 10
        case .medium:
            availableHints = 5
        case .hard:
            availableHints = 3
        case .extreme:
            availableHints = 0
        }
    }
    
    func updateCounts() {
        solved = false
        var newCounts = [Int: Int]()
        var correctCount = 0
        
        for row in 0..<board.size {
            for col in 0..<board.size {
                let value = board.playerBoard[row][col]
                
                if value == board.fullBoard[row][col] {
                    newCounts[value, default: 0] += 1
                    correctCount += 1
                }
            }
        }
        
        counts = newCounts
        
        if correctCount == board.size * board.size {
            Task {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
                showingNewGame = true
                solved = true
            }
        }
        
    }
    func getHintAvailable() -> String {
        if hintCount < availableHints {
            return "Még \(availableHints - hintCount) segítséged van!"
        } else if board.difficulty == .extreme {
            return "Extreme fokozaton csak magadra számíthatsz!"
        } else {
            return "Elhasználtad az összes segítséged!"
        }
    }
}
```

For example, if you select "hard" difficulty, it generates a hard board, "Board B". You can pick to play another board any time you want and it's going to be a different board. But, when you go to the WelcomeView and generate a board with the navigation link, if you choose the same difficulty that you choosed for "Board A", the game is going to generate the same Board as Board A.

So, here is the bug steps by steps:
1, choose easy on the WelcomeView.
2, finish Board 1, or ask for a different board for easy difficulty.
3, when you are on Board 2, hit the "Back" button that is going to bring you back to WelcomeView from GameView.
4, choose easy again.
5, you will get Board 1 again.

I've tried to somehow implement a UUID thing to every board the game generates, but i'm pretty much a newbie to programming, so I didn't know how to go forward

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the version of `NavigationLink` that is bound to state, then inside that state struct override the `didSet` to create the new game board.

Also about the code in general - it would be better to break all that up into smaller View structs passing in only the data each need, it's called tigther invalidation, so body only runs when the data it actually depends on changes. Just now any tiny change to one of the states causes the whole massive body to run and most of will just be the same Views.

In SwiftUI we use the `.task` or `.task(id:)` modifiers, not `Task { }`. You can have the `Button` set a bool that is checked by an if to show a View that has a `.task` (runs when it appears, cancelled when it disappears) or you can increment a counter and use `.task(id:counter)` to also cancel and restart when the counter changes.

Group the related view data state vars into a struct, like you did with `Board`.

Don't use a class if there is nothing being loaded from file or any async things happening.